# Can't update data through the Loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm currently working on an EEG system using the Arduino. The purpose of the system is to vibrate a vibrator for .1 seconds, wait .5 seconds, and then vibrate again for .1 seconds. However from the start I want it to read the EEG (Serial.println(brain.readCSV());      Serial.println(brain.readErrors());) every .1 seconds from the start.

The problem is that it only takes one sample and just repeats it throughout the process until it cycles, instead of continuously updating through the loop.

How can I get it to continuously read the new data while the entire system is operating.

```
#include "Brain.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

int n=0;
int m=0;

// Set up the brain parser, pass it the hardware serial object you want to listen on.
Brain brain(Serial);
int vib = 5;

void setup() {
    // Start the hardware serial.
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(vib, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // Expect packets about once per second.
    // The .readCSV() function returns a string (well, char*) listing the most recent brain data, in the following format:
    // "signal strength, attention, meditation, delta, theta, low alpha, high alpha, low beta, high beta, low gamma, high gamma" 
    if (brain.update()) {
        Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
        Serial.println(brain.readErrors());

        if(brain.readSignalQuality() == 0) {     
            // Vibrate
            digitalWrite(vib,HIGH);
            Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
            Serial.println(brain.readErrors());
            delay(100);
            while (n<500){
                n=n+100;
                digitalWrite(vib,LOW);
                Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
                Serial.println(brain.readErrors());
                Serial.println(n);
                delay(100);
            }
            digitalWrite(vib,HIGH);
            Serial.println(brain.readCSV());
            Serial.println(brain.readErrors());
            delay(100);
            while (m<10000){
                m=m+100;
                digitalWrite(vib,LOW);
                Serial.println(brain.readCSV());

                Serial.println(brain.readErrors());
                Serial.println(m);
                delay(100);
            }
            n=0;
            m=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do us a favor and format that code.  It’s really hard to follow when the blocks aren’t indented.  Hit control-t in the arduino IDE and it will do this for you.  It will make your code a lot easier to read and will make finding problems a lot easier.

Comment: If you want new data then you need to call brain.update again.

Answer (score 0):

As Delta_G says in the comments, you need to be calling brain.update() each time you want new data. Looking at the source code for [Brain.cpp](https://github.com/kitschpatrol/Brain/blob/master/Brain.cpp), notice that "readErrors" just returns a variable that only changes after you run update() (and readCSV runs sprintf on a bunch of variables that also get updated in update()). This implies that readErrors and readCSV don't actually pull new data.